VS22: Text editor colors are subdued
The color of selected text (and in general) is darker than the settings.
I checked, and indeed the color is influenced by the settings, e.g., setting it to red, but it appears darker.


[The AI keeps bothering me: "Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results."]
